# Iterating LinkedList using streams is altering result list due to RaceCondtion

Tags: java, java-8, linked-list, java-stream, parallel.foreach

We are iterating the LinkedList using Streams in java8, and creating another list. But due the race condition the result List size got alatered.

```
List<DesInfo> InfoList = new LinkedList<>();
documentList.stream()
            .parallel()
            .forEach(document -> {
                Info descriptiveInfo = objectFactory.createDescriptiveInfo();
                List<Document> documents = new ArrayList<>();
                documents.add(document);
                descriptiveInfo.setHotelInfo(getHotelInfo(document.get(CODE), documents));
                InfoList.add(Info);
            });
```

If we runt this code everytime we are seeing different size of InfoList got generated for the same documentList input. I gone through some forums and they mention like LinkedList is not thread-safe and to go for any thread-safe collection instead. But my requirement not allows me to change apart from LinkedList. I need to use parallel streams functionality with the same LinkedList.

Thanks,
Raghavan

Comment: You have to possibilities: Either use a synchronized collection or synchronize the access to the collection.

Comment: `getHotelInfo` seems to be an I/O bounded task. Parallel streams are meant to be used with CPU bounded tasks, so that they can take advantage of parallel *computation* (as opposed to parallel I/O). Lino's answer explains how to use the Stream API correctly, however it doesn't explain why this whole approach is flawed. If you need to do I/O in parallel, use the right tool, i.e. an `ExecutorService`, `CompletableFuture` (or maybe a 3rd party asynchronous tasks API).

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using a `forEach` use a `Collector` and a `map()` operation:

```
List<HotelDescriptiveInfo> hotelDescriptiveInfoList = documentList.parallelStream()
    .map(document -> {
        HotelDescriptiveInfo descriptiveInfo = objectFactory.createHotelDescriptiveInfo();
        List<Document> documents = new ArrayList<>();
        documents.add(document);
        descriptiveInfo.setHotelInfo(getHotelInfo(document.get(HOTEL_CODE), documents));
        return descriptiveInfo;
    })
    .collect(Collectors.toCollection(LinkedList::new));
```

The `Stream` api will take care of the handling and will not allow race conditions.

Answer (score 2):

Use `collect` instead of altering collection's state.

First create a mapping function:

```
private DesInfo documentToDesInfo(Document document){
    DesInfo info = objectFactory.createDescriptiveInfo();
    List<Document> documents = new ArrayList<>();
    documents.add(document);
    info.setHotelInfo(getHotelInfo(document.get(CODE), documents));
    return info;
}
```

Then use it in your pipeline:

```
List<DesInfo> infoList = documentList.parallelStream()
                                     .map(this::documentToDesInfo)
                                     .collect(toCollection(LinkedList::new));
```